# Clean Architecture and Use Cases in a diferents layers (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, architecture, bloc, clean-architecture

i'm already have implemented Clean Architecure + BLOC on mi app. The problem is, im not sure if a i can share use cases between diferents BLOC.

For example in this architecure:

App

|¬>Features

```
 |¬>Sales

   |¬>Data

   |¬>Domain

     |¬>UseCases

         |¬>GetAllSalesUseCase                

   |¬>Presentation

      |¬>Blocs

         |¬>SalesBloc


 |¬>Products

   |¬>Data

   |¬>Domain

     |¬>UseCases

         |¬>GetAllProductsUseCase                

   |¬>Presentation

      |¬>Blocs

         |¬>ProducsBloc
```

Should I share Usecase, **GetAllProducts** on **SalesBloc**, or y should have a repeated usecase?

Answer (score 0):

One of reason of the use case is it can be reusable. It's ok for you to use the same use case in different blocs.